# gnome 3.18 and .ovpn

Tags: networking, gnome, vpn, openvpn

I have a .ovpn I made from [here](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install/issues)

I tested the port is connecting w/ netstat:

```
$ nc -v -u -z -w 3 <ip> 443      
Connection to <ip> 443 port [udp/https] succeeded!
```

It looks like below.  I downloaded it and tried to get it to work with Gnome 3.18.  So far, not much luck.

On the client:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Then settings -> network-> + (lower left) -> VPN -> Import from file...

It shows up in the list, but if I enable it, browsers don't work.

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote <deleted> 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<deleted>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 2 (0x2)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ChangeMe
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 24 17:22:16 2017 GMT
            Not After : Mar 22 17:22:16 2027 GMT
        Subject: CN=mclaptop
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    <deleted>
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                <deleted>
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                <deleted>
                DirName:/CN=ChangeMe
                serial:A4:D8:96:4B:25:FD:DB:71

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         <deleted>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<deleted>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<deleted>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
<deleted>
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: Is your server pushing DNS to the clients? You also have to have the `push-redirect-gateway` statement setup on the server.

Comment: I rolled back your edit that added the answer to your question post. If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) (which you have done already) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was trying to use UDP on port 443 and it didn't work. Switched to port 53 (DNS) and it works ok.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)